# Magento2: Sometime js load sometime js not load properly

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, console

I got the JS error in console. Sometime when page load got the JS error and Sometime when page load it is working. I don't know what's the exact issue. I disabled all 3rd party extension after that got the same error on the website.

Please let me we need to upgrade jquery version.

Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Please help me on this.

Comment: Please share more details and which way use for add and call jquery ?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/326255/owl-carousel-randomly-not-loading-magento2-4/327814

Answer (score 0):

> **I have same problem with owl carousel slider Js. sometime js load and sometime show error. So at that time i found many solutions. And at last i found solution which is works well. There are two ways to include Js from the template in Magento 2:**

1. `<script type="text/x-magento-init">`

2. **data-mage-init** attribute.

Either way can be used to pass data to the script within the json definition.

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*':{
                owlcarousel:'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/owlcarousel',
                reltaed_js:'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/reltaed_js',
            }
        },
    shim:{
            'owlcarousel':{
                                 deps: ['jquery']
                          },
            'reltaed_js':{
                                 deps: ['jquery']
                          }
        }
};
```

> 1. For example, using the **x-magento-init** script tag, in the template you have:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "VendoreName_ModuleName/js/reltaed_js": {
                "slidername": "#you_id",
                "slideritems": "4"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> 2. For example, using the **data-mage-init** attribute into tag, in the template you have:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"reltaed_js": { "slidername": "Param1"}}'>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**reltaed_js.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'domReady',
    "owlcarousel",
], function ($,dom,owlCarousel) {
    'use strict';

    return function(config) {
        $(config.slidername).owlCarousel({
            items: config.slideritems,
            margin: 10,
            lazyLoad: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            autoplay: true,
            nav: true,
            dots:true,
            loop:true,
            slideSpeed: 300,
            paginationSpeed: 400,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    nav: true
                },
                480: {
                    items: 2,
                    nav: true
                },
                770: {
                    items: 3,
                    nav: true
                },
                1024: {
                    items: config.slideritems,
                    nav: true
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

> Add owl js at  **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/owlcarousel.js**
> **Rename owlcarousel.min.js to owlcarousel.js**

Add Owl CSS into your layout like this

```
<head>
    <css src="VendoreName_ModuleName::css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <css src="VendoreName_ModuleName::css/owl.theme.default.css" />
</head>
```

***Note: I recommend to use x-magento-init script tag***

***I Hope This Helps You***