# Stellar and Owl Carousel randomly show up as not a function

Tags: requirejs

I'm using the Porto Theme (of course - Porto is making trouble), and I randomly get console errors for both `$(...).owlCarousel is not a function` and `$(...).stellar is not a function`.

under design/porto_child I created requirejs-config.js which looks like this

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'js/jquery.stellar.min':'js/jquery.stellar.min',
        'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min': 'Smartwave_Porto/js/owl.carousel.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'js/jquery.stellar.min': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    },
    mixins: {
        'mage/collapsible': {
            'js/collapsible-mixin': true
        }
    }
};
```

This didn't change anything.

This is what's calling the Stellar function

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'js/jquery.stellar.min'
], function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).stellar({
            responsive: true,
            scrollProperty: 'scroll',
            parallaxElements: false,
            horizontalScrolling: false,
            horizontalOffset: 0,
            verticalOffset: 0
        });
    });
});
```

Any idea what else I can do?

Thank you

Comment: Try the below link solution, [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/327880/92172)

Answer (score 1):

Porto is already loading owl carousel in an inline  in the `Smartwave_Porto\templates\html\head.phtml` template so you don't really need to require it again in your child theme to use it.

I recommend extending porto's head.phtml in your child theme and removing the inline require config. Replace this with a requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
       paths:{
            'parallax': 'js/jquery.parallax.min',
            'owlcarousel': 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel',
            'owlcarousel_thumbs': 'owl.carousel/owl.carousel2.thumbs',
            'imagesloaded': 'Smartwave_Porto/js/imagesloaded',
            'packery': 'Smartwave_Porto/js/packery.pkgd',
            'floatelement': 'js/jquery.floatelement',
            'stellar':'js/jquery.stellar.min'
        },
        shim:{
            'parallax': {
              deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'owlcarousel': {
              deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'owlcarousel_thumbs': {
              deps: ['jquery','owlcarousel']
            },
            'packery': {
              deps: ['jquery','imagesloaded']
            },
            'floatelement': {
              deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'stellar': {
              deps: ['jquery']
            }
        }
};
```

The only other time I have seen similar random console errors is whilst bundling js. Are you using any bundling or M2 js optimiser?

Comment: Not using any bundling. I'll test the carousel

Comment: I see a bundle file showing up in pub/static even though I have bundling turned off in my settings.

Comment: Also check how your source js for stellar are wrapped up - compare them with the js included with porto as an example - although you said the errors are random - so the js does work sometimes?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes it works. When it does, everything works fine but it's too inconsistent

Comment: Delete the bundle file I guess, or at least check your console to see if it is being loaded. Actually the console error will tell you which js file is throwing the error, that would be the bundle file if it is loaded. The stellar parallax plugin is 8 years old! I am sure porto has a built in parallax.

Comment: Going to try to delete the file. I tried deleting the entire pub/static/frontend, but when I do, running deploy brings those files back

Comment: The bundle isn't loading, so I guess that's good. The carousel library loads even when I get the owlCarousel is not a function error

Comment: I recommend extending the porto head.phtml into your child theme and removing the inline require js from the template. Move them to your child themes requirejs-config.js.

Comment: Also in your paths config above the first part is an alias i.e. owlcarousel used by the require statement, you have used the path 'js/jquery.stellar.min'

Comment: If those paths have been set somewhere in the theme, shouldn't they work anywhere? Isn't that the point of requirejs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120337/discussion-between-paj-and-web-master).